# How I solve this TypeError in python?

Tags: java, python, python-2.7

I am working in python based on a Java code.

I have this in Java:

```
public static byte[]  datosOEM = new byte[900000];
```

I wrote this in Python following some documents that I found:

```
datosOEM=bytes([0x90, 0x00, 0x00])
```

When I run my program it shows me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 63, in <module> # The line 63 is the location of x1=datosOEM[k];
    x1=datosOEM[k];
IndexError:string index out of range
```

Craig correct this part and recommended me to change to this:

```
datosOEM = bytearray(900000)
```

Now, when I run my program it shows me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module> # The line 10 is the location of datosOEM = bytearray(900000)
    datosOEM = bytearray(900000)
TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem_'
```

**How I can fix this problem?**

Part of my code is this:

```
...
response=port.read(8)
print(response)
k=0
C=0
conexion=True
if(conexion):
    while(response>200):
        while(C==0):
            x1=datosOEM[k];
            if(x1=1):
                x2=datosOEM[k+1];
...
```

Comment: `if(x1=1):` , your program won't even compile.

Comment: all the x are on Java in this form:                              public static byte x1=0,x2=0,x3=0,x4=0,x5=0,x6=0;                        and I do not know how to pass that into python

Comment: Isn't 90000 the dimension of the byte array in Java? What is stored in datosOEM?

Comment: Then, what is your opinion about the first line?

Comment: I think "public static byte[]  datosOEM = new byte[900000];" means there are 900000 bytes in datosOEM.

Comment: But, Do you think that the Craig idea is wrong, or not? Remember that his idea was replace for datosOEM = bytearray(900000)

Comment: Here is a reference http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: What do you think about this idea? datosOEM = [0]*900000. to replace public static byte[] datosOEM = new byte[900000];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Craig certainly told you how to create a bytearray with 900000 bytes:

```
datosOEM = bytearray(5)
print(datosOEM)          # bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
datosOEM[0] = 65
print(datosOEM)          # bytearray(b'A\x00\x00\x00\x00')
```

Comment: What happen with the TypeError about the attribute ___getitem___?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the TypeError.

Comment: I just prove this code and The code do not show me any Error. Thank you very much. Another thing, this is sonund too much to ask but, Can you do me a favor to vote "Like" to this post and of course I vote "Like" to your answer, too. Please.